# Tidy up ggplot with Jitter and fixing axis labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

Hi guys, I have this very messy plot. How can I

- rotate the x axis text so that you can actually read it
- not include every y value in the y-axis (maybe have the y axis in intervals of 5)
- add jitter so that the plot is easier is read
- remove the NA values (I tried to, but I guess it did not work)
- remove the legend (had to crop it for confidentiality)

here is my code:

```
data <- ndpdata[which(ndpdata$FC.Fill.Size==20),] #20 fill size


library(tidyr)
my_df_long <- gather(data, group, y, -FC.Batch.Nbr)
data = my_df_long[2075:2550,]

 ggplot(data, aes(FC.Batch.Nbr, y, color=FC.Batch.Nbr), na.rm=TRUE) + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To rotate the x axis add this to your ggplot:

`theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))`

2. If you don't want to include every value on the y axis, you can set `breaks`:

`scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(251,270,290,310,325))`

3. To add jitter points try `position = "jitter"` inside `geom_point()`:

`geom_point(position = "jitter")`

4. To remove NA's you can use it on your data:

`data <- data[!is.na(data)]`

5. To remove legend add this to your ggplot:

`theme(legend.position = "none")`